# Excel doesn't save SQL query changes

Tags: sql, excel, ms-office

I'm having trouble with Excel saving changes I made in an embedded SQL query  to connect it with a MS SQL Server. The connection is DSN-less.

When I delete a WHERE-statement, save the workbook, then close it and open it again and go to connections window to check my connections, my changes to the SQL query are not there anymore.

But now comes the strange part: When I execute the SQL query it is executed as if my changes are still in it.

I hope someone can help me

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

create a view for query on db. follow data -> other sources -> from sql server on excel tab menu. username and password for db after that select view. conection is connections on data tab.

if you want to refresh, use refresh button on data tab.

Comment: I know how do embed a connection to a SQL Server. But that doesn't solve my problem